# how can i make 'mysql json index' in multi array?

Tags: mysql, json, indexing

```
[table] - document_change
id : integer,
change_json: JSON

[data]
------------------------------------------------------------
id: 1
change_json: 
[ 
  { master_no:111, change_data: [{name: 'a', content: 'b'}], delete_data: [{slave_no: 222}] },
  { master_no:115, change_data: [{name: 'z', content: 'x'}], delete_data: [{slave_no: 333}] }
]
------------------------------------------------------------
id: 2
change_json: 
[ 
  { master_no:222, change_data: [{name: 'd', content: 'e'}] },
  { master_no:223, change_data: [{name: 'e', content: 'f'}], delete_data: [{slave_no: 444}] }
]
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to make index on change_json->>master_no.

```
select * from document_change where 115 member of (change_json->'$[*].master_no');
```

I did get 1 row what i want.

But Execute Plan => Full Scan / Rows 2

So I made index like this

```
alter table document_change add index document_change_001 ((cast(change_json->'$[*].master_no' as char(255)) collate utf8mb4_bin));
```

But never indexing...

Answer (score 1):

Your `master_no` property is numeric. But index which you create indexes this property values as strings. Additionally you specify explicit collation. This everything causes the index expression to be not equal to one which is used in WHERE, and the index is ignored.

You must create index according to your condition.

```
ALTER TABLE document_change
  ADD INDEX idx_master_no ( (CAST(change_json->'$[*].master_no' AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)) )
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I0DxIAdR) with some notes.